# How to do CRL Check in a certificate, using something different from X509Chain (C#)?

Tags: c#, x509certificate, x509

In .net I am aware that I can use X509Certificate chain to validate the a given certificate.
I searched and found quite a few examples on how to do it. But if I want a little more control over it, I can't. By design it is very high level.
I was wanting something as low as this: [Nakov's code](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/12/01/x509-certificate-validation-in-java-build-and-verify-chain-and-verify-clr-with-bouncy-castle/).
Where I can download at will, and control the cache as I need or design.

Does anyone know any framework, or technique to use with BouncyCastle or IText?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use the standard  `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback.aspx

`An application can set the ServerCertificateValidationCallback property to a method to use for custom  validation by the client of the server certificate.`

Comment: You see, what I want to do is a tad different from that. The validation that I want to do is supposed to be used in a digital signature scenario, not a ssl opening connection.

Comment: But that is great, nonetheless, I always wanted to know that class name... ServicePointManager... Thanks a million

Comment: Wow, I completely missed that you weren't doing TLS.  That changes things!

Comment: @NoProblemBabe Could you get away with deriving off of X509CertificateValidator and overriding the Validate() method?  I've never tried this approach personally.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.x509certificatevalidator.validate.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Our SecureBlackbox offers TElX509CertificateValidator component which can be fully controlled and tuned up as you like. And if it's not enough, - TElX509CertificateValidator uses only functions and classes offered by SecureBlackbox so you can build your own validation procedures. SecureBlackbox supports OCSP requests and CRLs and much more

Comment: Sounds incredible, but I wan't to learn, Eugene. I was looking at it and it looks really concise. I will study it a little. thanks